# I am getting a Sql Syntax error while performing update query in java( java.sql.sqlsyntaxerrorexception you have an error in your sql syntax)

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

ERROR=(java.sql.SQL.SyntaxErrorException:You have an error in your SQL syntax;check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?, Last_Name=?, Contact=?, Email_ID=? WHERE Username=aman036' at line 1)

I am beginner in programming so any help will be appreciated. Here is my code:-

```
   Connection Con=null;
   PreparedStatement pst=null;
   ResultSet rs=null;

    String query="UPDATE cashier SET First_Name=?, Last_Name=?, Contact=?, Email_ID=?  WHERE Username=?";
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        Con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/billing","Aman","Amanbhattt");
        pst=Con.prepareStatement(query);
        pst.setString(1,NameField.getText());
        pst.setString(2,LastNameField.getText());
        pst.setString(3,ContactField.getText());
        pst.setString(4,EmailField.getText());
        pst.setString(5,UsernameField.getText());
        pst.executeUpdate(query);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data Updated Successfully");
        Con.close();
```

Comment: can you share more lines of error message, because your code is looking good.

Comment: java.sql.SQL.SyntaxErrorException:You have an error in your SQL syntax;check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?, Last_Name=?, Contact=?, Email_ID=?  WHERE Username=aman036' at line 1

Comment: I am really confuse.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error output. See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: @Aman can you please share full error track.

Answer (score 0):

@Aman

I d'not get your full error but from your code i identified you are not handle sql special characters in your code. you need to add escape character for your sql query.

```
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?, Last_Name=?, Contact=?, Email_ID=? WHERE Username=aman036'
```

In your Error Message I'm able see username append with  single quotes **aman036'**  so you need to remove that.

Please use the following code to remove special character in your sql query string

```
public String escapeMetaCharacters(String inputString){
    final String[] metaCharacters = {"\\","^","$","{","}","[","]","(",")",".","*","+","?","|","<",">","-","&","%"};

    for (int i = 0 ; i < metaCharacters.length ; i++){
        if(inputString.contains(metaCharacters[i])){
            inputString = inputString.replace(metaCharacters[i],"\\"+metaCharacters[i]);
        }
    }
    return inputString;
}

String query="UPDATE cashier SET First_Name=?, Last_Name=?, Contact=?, Email_ID=?  WHERE Username=?";
try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    Con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/billing","Aman","Amanbhattt");
    pst=Con.prepareStatement(query);
    pst.setString(1,escapeMetaCharacters(NameField.getText()));
    pst.setString(2,escapeMetaCharacters(LastNameField.getText()));
    pst.setString(3,escapeMetaCharacters(ContactField.getText()));
    pst.setString(4,escapeMetaCharacters(EmailField.getText()));
    pst.setString(5,escapeMetaCharacters(UsernameField.getText()));
    pst.executeUpdate(query);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data Updated Successfully");
    Con.close();
```

I know prepared Statement no need special character handling. But some times it's happened in prepared statement also. so please try this and let me know the issue resolved or not

I hope it helps you thanks